# How to get root privilege for Android NDK code on a rooted phone

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, root, raw-sockets

I'm trying to use raw socket in Android NDK C code. While accessing raw socket in Linux needs root privilege. I know that we can get root privilege for shell process by using Java code in a rooted phone:

Runtime.exec("su")

But the problem is how to get root privilege for my current thread/process but not the shell process?

Comment: You cannot.  Application code, including it's ndk libraries, cannot run as root.  Only helper processes can do that.

Comment: It *may* be possible to launch a helper program as root, have that open your raw socket, and then pass the file descriptor of that to your ndk library with sendmsg() and the fd-passing capability of unix domain sockets. The idea is that this would then give you a usable raw socket fd in unprivileged code which couldn't have opened it itself.  However, I'm not 100% sure this is allowed.  If it's not, you'll probably need to keep your helper running and have it act as a forwarding proxy to do raw socket ops on your behalf, interacting with it either via a unix socket or via its stdin/stdout.